# Call menubar from different folder

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to call menubar from different folder of my website. I did it by using php `<?php include("../../menu.php"); ?>`

But i am not able to call images of the menubar.
This method is suitable if everything is in the same folder. Is it possible to do it by using javascript?

Comment: You are absolutely able to call both PHP files and images stored in whatever folders you would like. How to do so depends entirely on your folder structure and files... which you've neglected to include.

Comment: You can also use JavaScript Ajax to bring all the html code from `menu.php`

Answer (score 0):

`Include` is ***not*** a function, and you don't have to use parentheses. Instead,  it is a language construct,  just like `echo`.

Try using this:

```
 <?php include "../../menu.php"; ?>
```

As for your image paths, you should set the image paths relative to the document root, so that it can accessed with the same path NO MATTER where in the site you are.

For this, add a `/` before all `src` in `<img>` tags, as this will set the path relative to document root and you would be able to access it from anywhere. For example,

```
<?php echo '<img src="/image.png"/>'; ?> //inside menu.php
```